# Unattended upgrade from Windows 7 to 10 with Autounattend.xml not working

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10

### What I'm trying to achive:

I want to be able to just start the setup for Windows 10 on an PC with Windows 7 installed so that after that initial interaction everything automatically works and upgrades the Windows 7 to Windows 10. After the Upgrade all files should be where they were before and all other Settings should be like they were before.

### My Problem:

Using a Autounattend.xml file created with the Windows System Image Manager dosen't work at all. If booted a boot medium like a CD it says the upgrade must be started from the installed OS.

When trying to start the setup.exe from the Installed Windows 7 it says that the Upgrade Path is not available.

Error Message in German:
[image: Screenshoot of the mentioned error in German]

[Autounattend.xml I'm trying to use.](https://pastebin.com/qqkbXB06)

To fix this I've tried [this](https://www.askvg.com/how-to-upgrade-from-windows-7-rc-to-rtm-build/) but without any success, I still get the same error. I also know that the other Settings in the Autounattend.xml work as I can use the settings to skip all OOBE stuff for a fresh install (if I add a user to be added to the file).

Another way I've tried to do it is using the following command:

```
Setup.exe /auto upgrade /showoobe none /pkey W269N-WFGWX-YVC9B-4J6C9-T83GX
```

This works quiet a bit better than the other way, it installs Windows 10 but it dosen't get rid of all oobe things. After first login it asks the default oobe questions starting with this:

[image]

So what that tells me is that since the Upgrade works with the second methode, that the upgrade path is not in fact not possible. But also since it still wants me to enter OOBE settings not exactly what I'm looking for.

### My Question:

Is there some "magic" setting I'm missing to make the Autounattend.xml work for the upgrade? Is there another way to completly automate the upgrade from Windows 7 to 10?

Answer (score -2):

have you tried to use the following :

Setup.exe /auto upgrade /quiet /showoobe none /pkey xxxxxxxxxxxxx

regards,
Chris

Comment: What part of this would actually solve the problem?

Comment: My guess would be the "/showoobe none" would try and suppress any of the OOBE (out of the box experience, i.e. the blue screen with the questions about setting up cortana and such). @chris, can you elaborate on the options and provide an explanation on what each does? For example, is it safe to assume that "pkey xxxxxxx" refers to the product key? Also, have you tested this? Does this work with Enterprise/KMS activated Windows 10 builds?